# Meaning of number in Starcraft 2 ladder?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2, what is the meaning of the number in the upper-right corner of the display?
(the 5320 in the image below)

[image: Starcraft 2 ladder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is your total number of achievement points. You may have seen random achievements pop up. This is the sum total of all you have received.